# GitLab CI/CD: no space left on device (docker)

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, gitlab, continuous-integration, filesystems

I am building a docker image in Gitlab. However, during the build, I receive:

```
Error processing tar file(exit status 1): write /app/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/rxjs/add/operator/map.js: no space left on device
```

If I run `df /var/lib/docker/`, I receive:

[image]

Docker images are deployed. in AWS.

None of the solutions on the Internet worked for me. Expecially, none of the solutions related to `docker system prune` worked.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: It appears you are trying to copy node_modules folder which is causing trouble, could you share your Dockerfile for better clarity ? Ideally you should be copying just the source along with package*.json and do installs as a later step.